# How to make docker container open to its host

Tags: docker, containers, couchdb

machine info: nectar virtual machine instance
The operating system: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal) amd64
security group: default + ssh + http
docker image info: ibmcom/couchdb3:3.1.1
command line typed and output:

command:
`docker pull ibmcom/couchdb3:${VERSION}` where version is set equal 3.1.1
output:

```
3.1.1: Pulling from ibmcom/couchdb3
Digest: sha256:784a43d1acd4cfa78a5fb4992a2d7a6aecec03d1b6a6458f443399abb8f38902
Status: Image is up to date for ibmcom/couchdb3:3.1.1
docker.io/ibmcom/couchdb3:3.1.1
root@yingrui1:/home/ubuntu#
```

command:

```
root@yingrui1:/home/ubuntu# docker create\
      --name couchdb${node}\
      --env COUCHDB_USER=${user}\
      --env COUCHDB_PASSWORD=${pass}\
      --env COUCHDB_SECRET=${cookie}\
      --env ERL_FLAGS="-setcookie \"${cookie}\" -name \"couchdb@${node}\""\
      ibmcom/couchdb3:${VERSION} --network host -p 8080:5984
```

where "node is a ip address

output:
`afe973a0515cb8d4a7acf13bcdf019f7b6029dcf291c449f0a2a1772f6c80234`

command:
`docker start couchdb@172.0.17.2` Note the "couchdb@172.0.17.2" is the container I just created
output:
`some long string`

command:
`docker ps`
output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                          NAMES
04aaabb201f1   ibmcom/couchdb3:3.1.1   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   4369/tcp, 5984/tcp, 9100/tcp   couchdb172.17.0.2
```

If I understand correctly, you need the ports shows the mapping like "4369->0.0.0.0" something. The current ports info shows it is not open its port to the host. So I wonder how can you do it? I have try `expose` and `-P` as well but neither of them works, I am really desperate now, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: `docker` options like `-p` need to come before the image name.  (You probably don't want `--network host`.)  Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run.

Comment: You are a legend man!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Maze pointed out, the problem is I should move the -p before the image name. What a silly mistake!